# How to get simple slopes for particular values in emtrends?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans

I have a mixed model with two categorical predictors (X1, X2) and one continuous predictor (X3).

```
model <- lmer(z ~ x1 * x2 * x3 + (1|group), data = data)
```

I am interested in comparing high and low traits of my continuous predictor.

My plan is to contrast the simple slopes for X3 (at -1 SD, M, +1 SD).

As far as I understand this can be done using the emtrends() function from emmeans like so:

```
sd1 <- mean(data$X3, na.rm = T) + sd(data$X3, na.rm = T)
mean <- mean(data$X3, na.rm = T)
sd2 <- mean(data$X3, na.rm = T) - sd(data$X3, na.rm = T)

mylist <- list(X3 = c(sd1, mean, sd2))

emtrends(model, ~ X1 * X2 | X3,
                      var = "X3",
                      at = mylist)
```

However, the coefficients provided are the same for the three values of X3.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Think about it. If you hold x1 and x2 fixed at their means, then your model is linear in x3, so has the same slope everywhere. I think you may want to specify a variety of x1 and x2 values.

Answer (score 0):

[simple_slopes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reghelper/versions/0.3.4/topics/simple_slopes) function in the [reghelper](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reghelper/index.html) -package could be an alternative to emmeans in this specific case. The following simulation probes simple slopes for the -1,0,1 values of x3 (that was simulated as having mean=0, sd=1), but you can of course use any values. For categorical predictors, all combinations as well as slope for x3 at the "mean" values of both categorical predictors are calculated:

```
library(lme4)
library(reghelper)
set.seed(42143)

#sample size
n=1000

#generate the factor variables (dummy coded)
x1<-sample(x = c(0,1),size = n,replace=T,prob=c(.90,.10))
x2<-sample(x = c(0,1),size = n,replace=T,prob=c(.90,.10))

#generate the continuous variable
x3<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=1)

#generate the group variable
group<-sample(letters,size=n,replace=T)

#generate the dependent variable with some main effect and three-way interaction weights
z<-0.2*x1-0.3*x2+0.4*x3+0.2*x1*x2*x3+rnorm(n)

#collect variables to a data frame
dat<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,group,z)

#run the model
model <- lmer(z ~ x1 * x2 * x3 + (1|group), data = dat)

#explore simple slopes at specified variables values. 
#"sstest" gives the slopes 

simple_slopes(model,levels=list(x1=c(0,1,mean(dat$x1),"sstest"),
                                x2=c(0,1,mean(dat$x2),"sstest"),
                                x3=c(-1,0,1,"sstest")))
```

Comment: However, the presumption in this answer is that there was something wrong with the `emtrends` output. There was nothing wrong with it, only problem was understanding that the slope is the same at every X3.